# values don't match level in R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

a few columns of a given data frame are factor level vectors, take one of them as example:

```
[4661] 12.7          13.2          10.1          12.3         
[4665] Not Available 12.7          Not Available Not Available
[4669] Not Available Not Available Not Available 11.1         
[4673] 9.9           9             Not Available 9.7          
[4677] 8.9           10.1          11.7          13           
[4681] Not Available 11.5          Not Available Not Available
[4685] 12.3          11.2          Not Available 11.1         
[4689] 10.4          Not Available Not Available Not Available
[4693] 11.5          Not Available Not Available Not Available
[4697] Not Available Not Available 12            Not Available
[4701] Not Available Not Available Not Available Not Available
[4705] Not Available Not Available
106 Levels: 10 10.1 10.2 10.3 10.4 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.9 ... Not Available
```

I find it annoying that it keeps saying the 106 levels start from 10 then 10.1, but in fact there are many values below 10, as shown in the above list.

How do I fix this, and have levels automatically match all values? Thanks.

Comment: Use `levels` function to know all of them.

Comment: This is a sensible design decision - you wouldn't expect R to print out every level when there could be millions of them.

Comment: @thelatemail my problem is that it (10,10.1,10.2) seems to suggest the lowest level is 10, while obviously there are many values smaller than that

Comment: @user6606453 - alphanumeric order "10" comes before "9","8","7" etc.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks!! THAT is what I didn't realize! Now it doesn't make sense to me, since I want to get the smallest value of this vector (I think that's 8.2). How to I adjust it formatting?

Comment: @user6606453 - I suggest you convert everything to numeric as per the last code in my answer below. Then you can simply do `min(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order to numeric order with some re-`factor`-ing

```
x <- factor(c(10,10.1,10.2,9,8,1,"Not available"))
levels(x)
#[1] "1"             "10"            "10.1"          "10.2"         
#[5] "8"             "9"             "Not available"


factor(x, levels=levels(x)[order(as.numeric(as.character(levels(x))),na.last=TRUE)])
#[1] 10            10.1          10.2          9             8             1             Not available
#Levels: 1 8 9 10 10.1 10.2 Not available
```

Arguably you should just be using this data as numeric in the first place, like:

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))
#[1] 10.0 10.1 10.2  9.0  8.0  1.0   NA
```